# Creating polygon with one click in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, autocad

How can i create a polygon inside a hole made by a set of other polygons?

blue X space on the image. I want to create polygon with one click, like in autocad with option BOUNDARY.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Digitizing tools plugin

with a simple click creates the polygon,
tool: fill gaps with a new feature

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe i didn't say that inside this shape file i have different attributes, that i choose when digitizing is finished

Comment: i can't find that plugin...
http://prntscr.com/d4605q

Comment: Found it. it is Digitizing Tools by  Bernhard Ströbl (Kommunale Immobilien Jena), Angelos Tzotsos (NTUA)

Comment: it's working :D